# Trigger the same action with two IDs

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, frontend

I have a modal which I would like to call with two buttons with different IDs. The reason is that one button is displayed on desktop and the other on mobile view (responsive). `display: none` does do the trick of using two times the same ID.

The modal:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="closecross">&times;</span>
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal as JS:

```
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closecross")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
```

My two buttons:

```
<div class="insertClass" id="myBtnMobile">Modal</div>
```

And

```
<div class="insertClass" id="myBtn">Modal</div>
```

I tried to use `getElementsByClassName('.myBtnMobile','.myBtn')` but it does not work with my JS.

The code I am using is from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp just to provide some potential playground.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you need two buttons other than giving them a different id, specially if they do the same thing?

Comment: Just attach your event handler to the two buttons, if you really need two, by calling `document.getElementById('...').onclick = function .....` twice

Comment: If I use the same ID again, only the first button will work. Another way would be to declare two IDs with getElementById(), but I can only put one argument inside. Is there a way to bind two IDs for the same function with my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/1140/)**

You could use `queryselectorAll()` :

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#myBtnMobile,#myBtn');

divs.forEach(function(div) {
  div.addEventListener("click", clickEvent);
});

function clickEvent() {
  console.log('Div ' + this.id + ' Clicked');
}
```

```html
<div id="myBtnMobile">Modal</div>
<div id="myBtn">Modal</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing: Webstorm/Uglyfy.js says: `ERROR: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;»`

Comment: Thank you very much. Learned something about querySelectorAll().

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this:

```
<div class="insertClass" id="myBtnMobile" onclick="yourfunction()">Modal</div>
<div class="insertClass" id="myBtn" onclick="yourfunction()">Modal</div>
```

or

```
document.getElementById("myBtnMobile").addEventListener("click", yourfunction);
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", yourfunction);
```

Or use

```
<button class="...">
```

not

```
<button id="...">.
```

One more possible solution:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('insertClass');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/43gkcm92/24/

Comment: Why not use id? even in your example you have unique id's

Comment: getElementById() does only take one ID. Is there a way to use more?

Answer (score 0):

you may this way to trigger two `ID` with same action

```
$('#myBtnMobile,#myBtn').click(function () {
      // your logic
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this envolves jQuery. I need a solution without this framework.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the class and not the ids:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("insertClass");
```

Comment: Thanks, but using the class selector does not work with my modal.